# When will java.net.URLEncoder.encode function throw UnsupportedEncodingException?

Tags: java, url-encoding

If I were to encode a string using the encode method of the URLEncoder class, when will it throw the UnsupportedEncodingException?

```
String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(myString, "UTF-8");
```

I have read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which reads,

> Throws:
>   UnsupportedEncodingException - If the named encoding is not supported

So, will this ever happen to my code if I always use "UTF-8"?

Comment: what is the value of `myString` ?

Comment: Well, thats what I want to know. Will it get thrown if I give any specific value to the string?

Comment: My question is what is the value  of that value ??

Comment: It won't happen if you use any of the standard encodings. It's just there in case you specify `"XYZ"`.

Comment: @Ravi It can be anything. I am trying to find out how and when the exception gets thrown. It can be a simple "Hello, world" to some strange one like "∞¢".

Comment: @EJP, any 'unencodable' strings?

Comment: actually you shouldn't received such exception until something wrong happened to your JVM

Comment: @EJP, I think I should now be asking, can someone give me an example of a string which is not encodable using UTF-8

Comment: There are no 'unencodable' strings, if a character does not exist in the target character set, it is replaced with either a `?` or the unicode replacement character `�` (or U+FFFD).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , that was the answer that I was looking for. Cheers! Any references that I can read further?

Comment: I'd start with the [`java.nio.charset` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/charset/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine with UTF-8, it depends on JVM installed on computer, where final application will run. Anyhow UTF-8 is now supported by java.

You can use static constants in StandardCharsets class:

URLEncoder.encode("Your string", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());

Comment: Lets say, with the latest JVM. Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12) :)

Comment: As far as you use `StandardCharsets` constants you are covered. Exception is thrown when you use different encodings. With UTF-8. You can check it here in doc [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)